# How to arrange components in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I'm trying to get a JTextArea with a "save" JButton centered underneath it, maybe with a small bit of padding between the components as well as the components to the frame if possible. I've tried messing around with layout managers, panels, etc. and can't seem to get the result i want. Just looking for the simplest way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: `"I've tried messing around with layout managers, panels, etc. and can't seem to get the result i want."` -- always show an image of your attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggestions:

- The overall layout of the GUI container could be BorderLayout.
- Add the JScrollPane that holds your JTextArea BorderLayout.CENTER.
- Create a JPanel just to hold the JButton and don't give it a specific layout manager. It will now use JPanel's default FlowLayout and will center components in the horizontal direction.
- Add your JButton to this last JPanel.
- Add that same JPanel to the GUI in the BorderLayout.PAGE_END (bottom) position.

For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleLayout extends JPanel {
    private static final int ROWS = 20;
    private static final int COLS = 60;
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLS);
    private JButton button = new JButton("Button");

    public SimpleLayout() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(button);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SimpleLayout mainPanel = new SimpleLayout();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot that worked. Exactly what i was looking for.